# Use context binded function like constrcutor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When we use  `Function.prototype.bind`  this is return new function and inside this function use  `Function.prototype.call`  and call our real function.


For example:

```
function User() {
    this.firstName = "Murad Sofiyev";
}
User = User.bind(window);
```

Top code snippet must mutated function like this

```
User = function() {
  User.call(window)
}
```

After this we want use User like **constructor** via **new** keyword this is must be return empty object but this is return object  `{ firstName: "Murad" }`  
Why? 

 
If we use   `Function.prototype.bind`  polyfill from MDN this is return empty object but builtin bind method return object like this   `{ firstName: "Murad" }` 
Can anyone explain this for me?

 
**Note: MDN Bind Polyfill Link** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Is there a real problem you're trying to solve here?  Or just a curiosity about some quirk that has no stated practical use.  I ask because I can't see how `User = User.bind(window);` would be practical in the context of a constructor function.  You want `new` to be able to properly set the `this` value for a constructor to a newly created object.  You don't want to try to override that behavior.

Comment: No this is not practical use case. This is only interesting for me :d

Comment: It's probably because the built-in `.bind()` remembers the non-bind function in some internal property and `new` uses that.   If you really want to know the details, some time studying the [relevant portions of spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf#page=132&zoom=100,0,36) will probably eventually explain it.  It hurts my head too much to try to follow this part of it myself.

Comment: @Manish I think you don't understand question :(

Comment: @jfriend00 Probably I think I must start read spec )))